# How to Integrate stripe in magento 1.9

Tags: magento, stripe-payments, magento-1.9

I want to integrate stripe on magento 1.9. I can't find free magento connect extension in magento market. Can any one have magento connect free stripe extension?

Answer (score 0):

Use this link you can download free extension for github  [https://github.com/ivanweiler/Inchoo_Stripe]

Comment: Thankyou for your valueable answer. but i got this error after uploading.CONNECT ERROR: Package file is invalid
Invalid package name, allowed: [a-zA-Z0-9_+] chars
Invalid version, should be like: x.x.x
Invalid stability
Invalid date, should be YYYY-DD-MM
Invalid channel URL
Empty authors section
Empty package contents section

Comment: How you install this

Comment: In magento connect manager, I just upload this file. in console that error occur. I tried it to as upload .rar and .zip but both time failed

Comment: upload direct to the file

Comment: Direct package file uploaded but still same issue

Comment: Still same issue